# visual studio 2022 changes debug mode from winUI to android, I want to work on the UI screens

Tags: c#, telerik, maui, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio changes the debug mode from winUI to Android, I want to work on the UI screens.

The debug type is the android emulator, I switch it to windows machine from the drop down, 1-2 seconds later it switches back to the android.

Here's a link show it in action: https://somup.com/c0ho3Daiiy

Here'e my VS info, it worked fine last week, but I was getting an error trying to run the camera to see if it would read a barcode.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.5.4
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.5.4+33530.505
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA502
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.5.318.41597
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.5.318.41597
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.5.318.41597
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.5.2-3.23171.7+d17f741546fad2786cbd6394d08619544e53a36d
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.4.3 (main@2a4517a)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   17.5.9 (11975e6)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   6.5.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Progress Telerik UI for Xamarin Extension   2023.1.426.51
Progress® Telerik® UI for Xamarin Extension

Progress Telerik WinForms Converter   2023.1.313.33
Progress® Telerik® UI for WinForms Converter

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.5.2.2316603+9f1b6856460af1e592d387ebef416eadddac453f
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.2.40120.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Telerik Reporting Tools   3.44.11.0
Complete .NET Reporting Solution for Web, Mobile and Desktop Applications. For more information please visit http://www.telerik.com/reporting. 

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20105.2003
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.5.2-3.23171.7+d17f741546fad2786cbd6394d08619544e53a36d
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)   17.0.33312.129
Visual C++ for Cross Platform Mobile Development (Android)

Visual F# Tools   17.5.0-beta.23053.5+794b7c259d9646a7eb685dad865aa27da7940a21
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Unity   17.5.1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Unity

VisualStudio.DeviceLog   1.0
Information about my package

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

VSPackage Extension   1.0
VSPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Xamarin   17.5.0.173 (d17-5@33e727c)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.5.3.46 (remotes/origin/d17-5@e4dd80b2bb)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.5.41 (ba80d05)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.0.0 (d17-5/797e2e1)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
    Mono: 6dd9def
    Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/main@149d70fe
    SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.0@fdc1e34
    Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@9f02d77


Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.2.0.5 (7738c90c9)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like VS doesn’t think Windows has been selected as a possible target.

To fix, open Project / Properties / Target Platforms:

- Make sure “Windows” is checked.
- If Windows already is, UNCHECK Android.
- If you can successfully get it to build and run Windows once, then you should be able to have both Windows and Android checked, and switch between them.

If still not working:

- Quit VS; delete solution’s hidden .vs folder.